# C# - Two DataTable comparison. Get Rows which are Updated, Deleted and Created(New)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

I have 2 DataTables: 1st DataTable is created today and 2nd Datatable was created yesterday.
Each DataTable contains over 100K rows and 30 columns.
I have a unique column - "Master_ID"

I want to compare and subtract (Today's DataTable - Yesterday's DataTable) and get the rows that are updated, deleted, and newly created. I want to perform a complete row-to-row comparison.

Output -> Dictionary <string, List DataRow >

1. Dictionary <"New Data Rows", List DataRow >
2. Dictionary <"Updated Data Rows", List DataRow >
3. Dictionary <"Deleted Data Rows", List DataRow >

I am looking for a time-efficient approach, probably using LINQ.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing in this?

Comment: I am trying to do it using a for, foreach loop, which is consuming a lot of time, provided the data is huge. I am looking for an efficient way to get the desired output.

Comment: you need to share these details and the code in the question. you also need to share how many rows the data tables have? how much time does your current code take to compare the table?

Comment: I have updated my question. I deleted the code as it was useless. Simply put two foreach loops comparing row to row.

Comment: You have a any column in the table which can identify the row a as unique? You should use that to look for matching row in the other table instead of checking the entire table.

Comment: You don't want the old values of the updated rows, only the new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one of the most efficient approaches is to use a dictionary-like collection to find out if a row-identifier is new, i'd use `ILookup<TKey, TValue>`:

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>?> GetChanges(DataTable dtNew, DataTable dtOld, string masterKeyName, StringComparer masterKeyComparer = null)
{
    IEqualityComparer<string> comparer = masterKeyComparer ?? StringComparer.Ordinal;
    ILookup<string, DataRow> newKeyLookup = dtNew.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(r => r.Field<string>(masterKeyName), comparer!)!;
    ILookup<string, DataRow> oldKeyLookup = dtOld.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(r => r.Field<string>(masterKeyName), comparer!)!;
    List<DataRow> updatedRows = new();
    List<DataRow> newRows = new();
    List<DataRow> deletedRows = new();

     foreach (var x in newKeyLookup)
     {
        List<DataRow> existingRows = oldKeyLookup[x.Key].ToList();
        if (existingRows.Any())
        {
            // potential update, check if there are changes:
            var allChangedRows = x.Where(r => !existingRows.Contains(r, DataRowComparer.Default));
            updatedRows.AddRange(allChangedRows);
        }
        if (!existingRows.Any())
        {
            newRows.AddRange(x);
        }
    }

    foreach (var x in oldKeyLookup)
    {
        if (!newKeyLookup[x.Key].Any())
        {
            deletedRows.AddRange(x);
        }
    }

    return new Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>?>
    {
        {"New Data Rows", newRows},
        {"Updated Data Rows", updatedRows},
        {"Deleted  Data Rows", deletedRows},
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for looking at this on my request. I tried this code and it's working fine for New and deleted records. However, it's not giving the correct result for the Update case. It's returning all records in the Update dict that are neither new nor deleted.

Comment: @Aashish: edited the answer, look at "// potential update"

Comment: Bingo. Thank you so much for this wonderful implementation. It's pretty fast and accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this code will help you. It takes each row in the new `DataTable` and looks for it in the old `DataTable` (to get the created and updated rows) and then takes all rows in the old table which weren't found in new table (to get deleted rows). It will work very slowly if your tables contain over 100K rows, so you'd better put it into a separate thread.

**My code will treat two different rows as one updated row if their `Master_ID` column is the same.**

```cs
DataTable oldTable, newTable; // Put there your tables
Dictionary<int, DataRow> deletedRows, newRows = new Dictionary<int, DataRow>(); // Here will be the result (key — row's Master_ID, value — the row)
var updatedRows = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<DataRow, DataRow>>(); // Here will be the result (key — row's Master_ID, value — tuple (first item — old row version, second item — new row version))

var commonIds = new List<int>();

foreach (var row in newTable.Rows) {
  var id = row["Master_ID"];

  if (oldTable.Contains(id)) {
    commonIds.Add((int)id);

    var rowInOldTable = oldTable.Rows.Find(id);

    foreach (var column in oldTable.Columns) {
      if (row[column] != rowInOldTable[column]) {
        updatedRows.Add((int)id, Tuple.Create<DataRow, DataRow>(rowInOldTable, row));
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    newRows.Add((int)id, row);
  }
}

deletedRows = (from row in oldTable.Rows
               where !commonIds.Contains((int)row["Master_ID"]))
              .ToDictionary<DataRow, int>(row => (int)row["Master_ID"]);
```

Comment: Which .NET Framework is used for this code?

Comment: @Chetan This will work on .NET Framework 4.5 or higher (maybe on earlier versions it will work too, but I can't say for sure).

Comment: Thank you SNBS for your answer.

Comment: @Aashish But did it work? If yes, can you accept my answer?